# ANR on Android N using Nexus 6P

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog, android-7.0-nougat

I'm testing App, and got ANR (only on Android N, and not on other version). It doesn't always happens and not always at the same place, and can't replicate whenever in debug mode.

The only pulling the traces.txt out using `adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt` command. The closest related txt within the traces.txt is below.

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x76134f58 self=0x7b95695a00
  | sysTid=4058 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b9944da98
  | state=S schedstat=( 4148388502 271817611 2852 ) utm=371 stm=42 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fdafd1000-0x7fdafd3000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0x98
  kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd4/0x130
  kernel: futex_wait+0xfc/0x210
  kernel: do_futex+0xe0/0x920
  kernel: SyS_futex+0x11c/0x1b0
  kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c
  native: #00 pc 000000000001bc6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 0000000000069304  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL33__pthread_mutex_lock_with_timeoutP24pthread_mutex_internal_tbPK8timespec+776)
  native: #02 pc 00000000006d4070  /data/app/com.android.chrome-2/base.apk (???)
  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwGLFunctor.nativeDestroy(Native method)
  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwGLFunctor.access$000(AwGLFunctor.java:23)
  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwGLFunctor$DestroyRunnable.run(AwGLFunctor.java:36)
  at org.chromium.content.common.CleanupReference.runCleanupTaskInternal(CleanupReference.java:164)
  at org.chromium.content.common.CleanupReference.access$300(CleanupReference.java:33)
  at org.chromium.content.common.CleanupReference$LazyHolder$1.handleMessage(CleanupReference.java:96)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

But I can't interpret it well. It looks like related to some webview onDestroy code. But I'm not sure. Please advise how could I go about to further debug this, or anyone faced this before to shed some light?

Comment: I saw essentially the same trace on a Moto G running Android Lollipop, so I don't think it's specific to Nougat. There are a couple other WebView ANR bugs in the [Chromium bug list](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list), but nothing like this exactly. Is your WebView inside a ViewPager?